# convert maven local repository to remote repository

Tags: maven-2, maven

I have a repository directory under .m2 that I want to use as a remote repository (-Dmaven.repo.remote=http://remotehostname/repo) to other hosts.  I tried just to expose the directory .m2/repository/ under Apache as http://remotehostname/repo, the directory is fully visible via HTTP, but Maven doesn't seem to be reading from the exposed repo.  For various reasons, I do not want to add this new remote repo to settings.xml; limit it to -Dmaven.repo.remote

What do I need to do to convert a local repo under .m2 as a remote repo?

Answer (score 2):

Further to @Perception's answer, you can look at [Nexus Command Line](https://docs.sonatype.com/display/SPRTNXOSS/Nexus+Command+Line+Tools) tool, which can help convert your local repo to nexus repo

Comment: The website is not accessible anymore.  The latest version 2.2.1 from 2012 can be downloaded from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/nexus/tools/nexus-repository-conversion-tool/2.2.1/ - get the -cli.jar as it can be run directly.   Use -h to get a command summary

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard of any maven repository manager that can simply mirror your .m2 folder (which is just a local repository). You need to install and configure repository management software ... there are many free, open source ones, I recommend [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/products.php) or [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/).

Nexus does fit very closely with your requirements since it uses a file based repository, and the file layout matches with the local repo layout.